# Date formatting in moment.js , weird date values

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

So I have 2 kinds of date coming from json.

```
m = '201811';
n = '/Date(1433030400000)/';
```

I am trying to use moment.js to format time, but I can not find appropriate methods for it I guess.

```
moment(m).format('YYYY DD') //"201811 01"
```

and the n value I can not understand it leads to this output :

```
moment(m).format('YYYY DD')//"2015 31"
```

Comment: The first looks more like yyyy mm (2018-11). The second looks like a time value in milliseconds, so just get the digits, convert to a Number and pass to the Date constructor: `new Date(1433030400000)` which returns a Date for 2015-05-31T00:00:00Z.

Comment: Please describe *exactly* what `m` is. Is `201811` the 11th day of year 2018?  Or is it the first day of month 11? Or day 11 of some unspecified month? How are we to guess? You need to tell us.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass a date to `moment()` constructor, you might have to specify in what format it is.

So for the first date you would need to do:

```
moment(m, 'YYYYMM').format('YYYY MM'); // if the date is indeed in the form YYYYMM
```

For the second date, just extract the numeric part from the string and feed it to `moment`:

```
var ts = n.match(/(\d+)/);
moment(+ts[1]).format('YYYY DD');
```

See the snippet:

```js
var m = '201811';
var n = '/Date(1433030400000)/';

alert(moment(m, 'YYYYMM').format('YYYY MM'));

var ts = n.match(/(\d+)/);
moment(+ts[1]).format('YYYY DD');

alert(moment(+ts[1]).format('YYYY MM'));
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

**EDIT:**

thanks to @MattJohnson, if you have at least moment version 1.3.0, you can simply pass the string in the form `/Date(1433030400000)/` to the `moment()` constructor, and it will automatically detect the proper format, see also [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/asp-net-json-date/).

Comment: There's no need for the extra work on `n`.  [Moment supports that format natively](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/asp-net-json-date/).

Comment: Thanks! Added a note about it :)

Answer (score 0):

Just pass them to moment in the following format:

```
var m = '201811';
var n = '/Date(1433030400000)/';

var formattedM = window.moment(m, 'YYYYMM').format('YYYY MMM DD'); //2018 Nov 01

var formattedN = window.moment(n).format('YYYY MMM DD'); //2015 May 31
```

I've dropped an example into [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/dewugecoqu/1/edit?html,js,output).

Thanks to [Matt Johnson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/634824/matt-johnson) for pointing out that moment can take the `/Date(1433030400000)/` format.

Comment: There's no need for the eval on `n`.  [Moment supports that format natively](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/asp-net-json-date/).